# Term for a access control model based on users sharing resources with each other?

Tags: permissions, terminology

A very simple access model: I have users and resources. Each resource has an owner. Owners can can grant other users read and write permissions to resources they own (and transfer ownership). So essentially each resource has a policy that says who can do what with it.

I know RBAC, ABAC, but I am not sure what is the official term for the model I described.

Comment: confuses with OBAC but its DAC as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have described the classic "Discretionary Access Control (DAC)" model.

https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/certification/access-control-models-and-methods/